# Django models to have a shared calculated field

Tags: python, django

I have 3 Django models that shared a few common attributes and then they have lot of other attributes that make them different. Example:

**Model1**

- quality_score
- other attributes specific to Model1

**Model2**

- quality_score
- other attributes specific to Model2

**Model3**

- quality_score
- other attributes specific to Model3

I need to create a calculated field like this:

```
def _get_quality_band(self):
        if self.quality_score is None:
            return ''
        elif self.quality_score > 0 and self.quality_score <= 10:
            return 'bad'
        elif self.quality_score > 10 and self.quality_score <= 19:
            return 'average'
        elif self.quality_score > 19 and self.quality_score <= 28:
            return 'good'
        else:
            return ''
quality_band = property(_get_quality_band)
```

Is there a way to make the 3 models share this property instead creating it in every model?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You could have an abstract base class and then inherit from it:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
  quality_score = models.IntegerField()

  @property
  def quality_band(self):
    # do something with self.quality_score

  class Meta:
    abtract = True

class Model1(BaseModel):
 # Your specialized fields

class Model2(BaseModel):
 # Your specialized fields
```

All instances of `Model1` and `Model2` will have `quality_score` and `quality_band` members.